# Displaying initial value in ComboBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

Trying to display the initial value in a `WPF` `ComboBox` that implements some `Material Design Toolkit` style. But problem is, it doesn't show the value or text that i am assigning to it `On-Load`. It just display white space. The value is there and that can be confirmed by the HINT text of Material Toolkit. The hint text goes up which means text is loaded but it doesn't display it. Please see this attached image.

[image]

**Xaml**

```
<ComboBox Name="CategoryBox" Margin="20 0 0 0" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Category"
                  materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="True" materialDesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity=".26">
</ComboBox>
```

**Displaying Value on Load**

```
CategoryBox.Text = "blah blah";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this trick. by setting these properties `true` the above problem is solved. and now `CategoryBox.Text = "blah blah";` works fine !

```
        CategoryBox.IsReadOnly = true;
        SupplierBox.IsReadOnly = true;
        CategoryBox.IsEditable = true;
        SupplierBox.IsEditable = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `IsReadOnly` property as `true` in the related combo boxes.